# Android - How to access method in fragment from child SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a SurfaceView as the view of a fragment and I want to access the variable diffRadius from the fragment in the SurfaceView. How would I go about accessing the get function in the fragment.

Fragment Code

```
public class AsteroidsFragment extends Fragment {

private AsteroidsView asteroidsView;
public int diffRadius;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
    GameActivity activity = (GameActivity) getActivity();
    diffRadius = activity.getDiffRadius();
    asteroidsView = (AsteroidsView) view.findViewById(R.id.asteroidsView);
    return view;
}
public int getDiffRadius()
{
    return diffRadius;
}
```

SurfaceView Code

```
public class AsteroidsView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
public AsteroidsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    activity = (Activity) context;

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //Set diffRadius to ParentFragment.getDiffRadius()

    asteroidPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
}
```

Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the SurfaceView to have a hard dependency on the fragment, but you can communicate through an interference

1. Create a RadiusProvider interface
2. Make the fragment implement that interface
3. Create a method in the Surface view for setting a radiusProvider.

On the interface

```
public interface RadiusProvider {
    int getDiffRadius();
 }
```

On the fragment

```
public class AsteroidsFragment extends Fragment implements RadiusProvider { 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
        asteroidsView = (AsteroidsView) view.findViewById(R.id.asteroidsView);
        asteroidsView.setRadiusProvider(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDiffRadius() {
        return diffRadius;
    }
```

On the SurfaceView

```
public class AsteroidsView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    ....
    public void setRadiusProvider(RadiusProvider radiusProvider) {
        this.radiusProvider = radiusProvider;
    }
}
```

That way the SurfaceView knows how to get the radius but it doesn't know anything else about the fragment and that fragment could be swapped for any other object that implements RadiusProvider and the SurfaceView wouldn't care.